# What are the messages in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, netflix

I was going through a tutorial on Apache Kafka. It said that netflix has 4000 brokers across 36 clusters processing over 700 billions messages per day.

What does these messages can refer to when we talk in the context of Netflix?

Comment: Kafka message could be any event in their micro service architecture like user has watched movie, user opened a specific web page, granting a bonus to someone etc. Kafka messages are the way to asynchronously communicate between applications (in contract with synchronous REST invocations).
you need directly ask to Netflix about what type of messages they send

Comment: An additional note is that the term "streaming" is overloaded. Netflix as a video streaming service does not serve those streams through Kafka. This is not a suitable use case for Kafka. The streaming Kafka is involved in is real time data analysis and transport but more like things you would store in a database or event sourcing kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core abstraction Kafka provides for a stream of records is known as topic. You can imagine topics as the tables in a database. A database (Kafka) can have multiple tables (topics). Like in databases, a topic can have any kind of records depending on the usecase.

For Netflix particularly, we might have a topic `users` that contains the users of the platform:

```
{"userId":"1", "firstName":"Giorgos", "lastName":"Myrianthous"}
```

or a topic `movies` that contains movies' details:

```
{"movieID":"1", "title":"Titanic", "genre":"drama", "rating":"5"}
```

Other topics might also include data that serve internal analytical/business intelligence tools, machine learning algorithms (like recommendation engines) or alerting mechanisms.

Data within a topic can be represented by various types such as String, JSON or Avro.